# List Item Tpl issue: List that has not been rendered with two arrays as two columns

Tags: html, list, css, sencha-touch-2

I am newbie to the sencha touch and came across with the following problem.
I have to display the list that has variable height(of course it is default), which consist of text display along with images. The items which are been populated in the list are arrays, one array needs to be left side and other one is at right side, some how i used span and added for loop in the item TPL to iterate over the arrays. the first array (left array) got displayed properly as expected and for the second array which is to be displayed at right side is being rendered after the left array completed.I have attached the image how it looks now, So i need to display them side by side, there might be a CSS problem, tried the various alternatives but of no use, can anybody know what would be the problem by looking into the below code and CSS, Thanks for you help.

**ItemTpl:**

```
                     '<div class="listItem">' +
                    '<span><tpl for = "firstArray">'+
                    '<span class="listSecondRow">'+
                    '<img src="resources/images/someImage.png"/>' +
                    '<label>{data} {data}</label>' +
                    '<img src="resources/images/someImage.png"/><label>{data}</label>' +
                    '<img src="resources/images/someImage.png"/><label>SKD {data} </label>' +
                    '<label>{data}</label><br>' +
                    '</span></tpl>'+
                     '<span><tpl for = "secondArray">'+
                     '<span class="listSecondRow2">'+
                     '<img src="resources/images/image.png"/><label>{data} {data}</label>' +
                     '<img src="resources/images/image.png"/><label>{data}</label>' +
                     '<img src="resources/images/image.png"/>' +
                     '<label>SKD {data} </label>' +
                     '<label>{data}</label><br>' +
                     '</span></tpl></span>'+
                    '</div>',
```

Comment: .listSecondRow {
    margin-right: 85px;
  }

.listSecondRow2 {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}

.listItem {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #B2B2B2;
    border-top: 5px solid #B2B2B2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: .5em;
    direction: ltr;
}


forgot to add CSS, here is the css

Answer (score 0):

By modifying the CSS and removal of complete item Tpl tags for this columns resolved the issue